# Can not Find duplicates in columns within id

Tags: database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qACt.png)[Find duplicates in DATABASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/famKl.png)

expected result: by order_id (255) find duplicates in column date_from and date_to:
2023-07-03 and 2023-06-27
(There may be duplicates with other order id, just in this case one was fixed.
please, open attached image - detailed information is in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify database you use, but code I'm going to post should work anywhere. Basically, you're searching for rows whose combination of [date from + date to + order id] has duplicates. That will be calculated within a subquery, while the main query just fetches all columns from that table, for all rows that satisfy condition.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test;

DATE_FROM DATE_TO     ORDER_ID  OFFICE_ID
--------- --------- ---------- ----------
09-JUN-23 12-JUN-23        254          1
27-JUN-23 27-JUN-23        254          2
03-JUL-23 18-JUL-23        254          2
03-JUL-23 03-JUL-23        255          2
03-JUL-23 03-JUL-23        255          3
27-JUN-23 27-JUN-23        255          4
27-JUN-23 27-JUN-23        255          5
09-JUN-23 12-JUN-23        255          7

8 rows selected.
```

Query:

```
SQL> select * from test
  2  where (date_from, date_to, order_id) in
  3         (select date_from, date_to, order_id
  4          from test
  5          group by date_from, date_to, order_id
  6          having count(*) > 1
  7         )
  8  order by date_from desc, office_id;

DATE_FROM DATE_TO     ORDER_ID  OFFICE_ID
--------- --------- ---------- ----------
03-JUL-23 03-JUL-23        255          2
03-JUL-23 03-JUL-23        255          3
27-JUN-23 27-JUN-23        255          4
27-JUN-23 27-JUN-23        255          5

SQL>
```